# Changing properties of an object

Tags: ocaml

I've got a type representing a tree:

```
type 'a tree =
    | Null
    | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree * 'a tree ref;;
```

And my objective is to write a function `'a tree -> unit` that takes tree and changes it in such a way, that every node has a reference to the next node in infix order (the last node points to Null).

How to change a given tree without returning it?

Comment: Please don't, if u r trying to write ocaml like Java

Comment: Not my idea - that's my assignment in computer science course

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that makes a tree node point to itself:

```
 let circulate tn =
     match tn with
     | Null -> ()
     | Node (_, _, _, tr) -> tr := tn
```